# Latest Article Popup

Tags: 7, javascript, notifications

I've seen this functionality being used quite often especially on news sites where latest articles snippets/calls-to-action pop out of the side of the browser - See image below:

[image]

Any idea what is the most common way this implementation is handled in Drupal?

I had a look at a couple of Drupal modules but didn't strike it lucky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [Flippy](https://www.drupal.org/project/flippy) module.

```
 1. Go to desired content type -> admin/structure/types/manage/<content_type>
 2. Click on Flippy Settings tab
 3. Select "Build a pager for this content type"
 4. Customize the module or template, theme as you want.
```

Comment: Hi Nagarjuna. Thanks, will check it out. Example of the popout "widget" can be seen here on the right side of the page: http://mybroadband.co.za/news/smartphones/155965-samsung-galaxy-s7-vs-galaxy-s6-specifications-and-feature-comparison.html. I take it Flippy can emulate that?

Comment: Yes, we can achieve that. This module will create a links in left and right side of window.

Comment: Never heard about this module, interesting!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what you're looking for is slidebox.  It's working quite well.  AFter the install make sure you clear your cache and rebuild your registry.  You'll also need to create some content (likely via blocks) and then drop that content into the right region.  You could also likely use context.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for the info. Haven't given this module a shot yet as Flippy recommended above has allowed me to expose custom on-page pagers in the way that meets our requirements. Will bookmark your recommendation and check it out at a later stage as a possible alternative.